# this.setState inside the callback of this.setState not setting state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 list items which uses the same `<ListItem />` component with `this.props.a = true` and `this.props.b = true` passed to it from a parent component (mentioning there are 2 because I am not sure that messes with anything but each of them should have their own independent component state) .

In the `<ListItem />` component I have an `_handleOnClick` function. When the `_handleOnClick` function is fired, inspecting the component state shows `a: false` and `b:true` although I see `got here` logged in my console.

I would have expected `this.setState({ b: false })` to be called in the callback and the state to change to `a: false` and `b:false`. What am I missing?

```
export default class ListItem extends PureComponent {
    state = {
        a: this.props.a, //this.props.a is true
        b: this.props.b, //this.props.b is true
    };

    _handleOnClick = () => {
        this.setState({ a: !this.state.a }, () => {
            if (!this.state.a && this.state.b) {
                console.log('got here')
                this.setState({ b: false })
            }
        });
    };

...
}
```

Comment: can't see any unexpected on your code. when _handleOnClick is called: a === true & b ===true, after first setState a === false & b === true son pass your if and log got here, after that setState should change b to false and finally got a === false, b === false

Comment: When you are in the callback the value of this.state.a has been already changed. 
check this fiddle https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-franklin-5q5ih

you should try to change state all in one batch call, setState({a:... , b:...})

Comment: this is causing unexpected results because I am setting local state and also dispatching actions to change the props which the state is dependent on.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try this

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
//add your stuff here by matching it with previous state
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting derived state from props?  I believe it's considered an anti-pattern to store anything in a state that can be derived from props at any point in time.

also https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

That being said, I believe your first argument is supposed to be the full state object.
[what-is-the-difference-between-passing-an-object-or-a-function-in-setstate](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-passing-an-object-or-a-function-in-setstate)